# Toggle tab for javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am developing log-in panel for my web site. For that I have used single tab. First, it displayed "forgot username or password" in right corner of page. When the user clicks on this tab it displays "Remembered it? Sign in!" But the page should change to forgot pass word page.

Plz find below images(It has taken from http://www.picnik.com/app#/home/welcome)

Normal page:

[image]

After clicking on "Forgot your username" it should look like:
[image]

After that when I click on sign in it should navigate to the previous page which is username and password asked page.

it should in javascript or jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If its just this, then there is no need for tabs. You can just make them containers and images. Either us polygon as a map or you can use an absolute position on the "tabs" as images. When you click just show and hide what is necessary using .hide() and .show(). You show no code or any attempt, so this is what you get.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to switch from one display to another? Whether or not to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `box1.style.display = "block"; box2.style.display = "none";` on the "Remembered it" link and `box1.style.dislpay = "none"; box2.style.display = "block";` on the "Forgot it" one, where `box1` is the login box and `box2` is the password recovery box (which you can get with `getElementById()`), and you're done.